# PHP Fatal Error Call to undefined method

Tags: php, database

I've been looking for a solution to my problem but every case seems to differ from mine. I'm attempting to import a CSV file using PHP.

This is the Error I receive:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Teacher::email_teacher() in C:\wamp\www\Projet\models\Db.class.php on line 66

This is from **index.php**. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

define('VIEW_PATH','views/');
define('CONT_PATH','controllers/');

$csvfileTeacher = 'models/professeurs.csv';


function uploadClass($classe) {
        require 'models/' . $classe . '.class.php';
    }
    spl_autoload_register('uploadClass');


function getTeacher($csvfileTeacher) {
    $teachers = array ();
    if (file_exists ( $csvfileTeacher )) {
        $fcontents = file ( $csvfileTeacher );
        $i = count ( $fcontents ) - 1;
        for($index = 1; $index <= $i; $index ++) {
            $icontent = $fcontents [$index];
            preg_match ( '/^(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*)/', $icontent, $result );
            $teachers [$index] = new teacher ( $result [1], $result [2], $result [3], $result [4] );
        }
    }
    return $teachers;
}

if (file_exists ( $csvfileTeacher )) {

    $teachers = getTeacher ( $csvfileTeacher );

    foreach ( $teachers as $teacher ) {
        Db::getInstance ()->insert_teacher ( $teacher );  ///here is where the problem seems to be 
    }

}
```

Here is the function insert_teacher() from **Db.class.php:**

```
public function insert_teacher($teacher) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO teachers VALUES ( ' . $this->_db->quote ( $teacher->email_teacher () ) . ',' . $this->_db->quote ( $teacher->firstname_teacher () ) . ',' . $this->_db->quote ( $teacher->lastname_teacher () ) . ',' . $this->_db->quote ( $teacher->supervisor () ) .')';          
    $this->_db->prepare ( $query )->execute ();
}
```

This is the teacher class:

```
<?php
    class Teacher{

        private $_email_teacher;
        private $_firstname_teacher;
        private $_lastname_teacher;
        private $_supervisor;

        public function  __construct($email_teacher,$firstname_teacher,$lastname_teacher,$supervisor){

            $this->_email_teacher=$email_teacher;
            $this->_firstname_teacher=$firstname_teacher;
            $this->_lastname_teacher=$lastname_teacher;
            $this->_supervisor=$supervisor;
        }

        public function email(){
            return $this->_email_teacher;
        }

        public function firstname(){
            return $this->_firstname_teacher;
        }
        public function lastname(){
            return $this->_lastname_teacher;
        }

        public function supervisor(){
            return $this->_supervisor;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: You edited this to put in the function for insert_teacher().  But your error specifies that email_teacher() is the one that is undefined.

Comment: What's unclear? You don't have a function named `email_teacher` Write it or remove it's call.

Comment: try removing ending parenthesis from "$teacher->email_teacher ()".
If I've rightly understood, you are calling a property, not a method.

Comment: Line 66 refers to the insert_teacher() function, that is why I have inserted it.

Comment: I tried to remove the parenthesis but I get an error "Undefined property: Teacher::$email_teacher"

Comment: Your error refers to an undefined method in a class whose code is not included in your question. Apparently you are able to create the teacher object or you would have an error before the one you are getting. You just need to look at the teacher class and make sure the method you are calling is defined there. Maybe you're just not using the correct name for the method?

Comment: @Don'tPanic As you mentionned my teacher class was missing some elements, I have fixed them but I still get the same error. Should I post the teacher class for you to view it ?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method definitions in the teacher class, it appears that the problem is that you are not using the correct names for the methods.

```
$teacher->email_teacher ()
```

needs to be

```
$teacher->email()
```

The `email()` method returns the property `_email_teacher`.

Methods like `email()` are referred to as accessors. They are used to access private properties of an object. The leading underscore in `_email_teacher` is a commonly used naming convention to indicate that a property is private.

Comment: I believe that was the issue! Once again Thank you for your time and help sir!